# Agregar background a una celda en función de una condición

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo añadir color de background a una celda concreta en base a una condición. Es decir, si se cumple que en la columna 1 de la línea 1 el número de esa celda comienza por un 1, que la celda de la columna 7 de la línea 1 se pinte en rojo, por ejemplo. De momento lo que tengo es la línea de exportación a Excel con pandas:

```
    dfDiferencias_21=pd.DataFrame({'Código artículo':referencias, 'Artículo':articulos,'Media de unidades vendidas en los últimos tres meses':ventas, 'Pvp':pvp, '¿Comienz el código por 1?':esCodigoValido})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la versión 1.17.1 se agregó la posibilidad de usar formateo condicional al DataFrame. Los estilos se muestran en Jupyter Notebook por ejemplo y se pueden también exportar a Excel.

> **Advertencia:** actualmente (versión 0.23.4) esta característica sigue estando marcada como "bajo desarrollo" aunque está bastante madura, por lo que es posible que en nuevas versiones se hagan cambios que rompan la compatibilidad con versiones anteriores. Usar con cuidado.

Podemos usar `pandas.Style.apply` junto a una función que use `numpy.select` para tener una forma genérica especificar el color de fondo de cada celda de una columna en base a una o varias condiciones cualquiera:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



def highlight_col(column, bool_masks, color_list, default="white"):        
    cond_bg_style = [f'background-color: {color}' for color in color_list]
    default_bg_style = f'background-color:{default}'
    return np.select(bool_masks, cond_bg_style, default=default_bg_style)

# DataFrame aleatorio de ejemplo
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
masks = [data.A >= 0,
        (data.A >= -1) & (data.A < 0),
         data.A < -1
        ]    
colors = ["green", "#ffbf00", "#ff3333"]

styled = data.style.apply(highlight_col, subset=["B"],
                          bool_masks=masks, color_list=colors
                          )
styled.to_excel("foo.xlsx", sheet_name='Hoja1')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El segundo parámetro de la función es una lista de arrays de booleanos, donde cada item (`True` o `False`) indica si la celda en esa posición debe o no tener el color de fondo que le corresponde según la lista `color_list`, por ejemplo para:

```
masks = [[True, False, False, True],
         [False, False, True, False]]
colors = ["red", "green"]
```

las celdas para las que en su posición tiene `True` en el primer array tendrán un fondo en rojo (la primera y la última). Las que tiene `True` en el segundo lo tendrán en verde (la tercera). Aquellas celdas que no cumplen ninguna condición tendrán el color especificado en el parámetro `default` (blanco si no se especifica). Si hay una celda que tiene varios colores asignados se queda con el primero que se le asigne.

En tu caso, la creación de la máscara booleana en función de los valores de la primera columna (primer dígito del mismo es 1) dependerá por ejemplo del tipo de dato que esta contiene. Por ejemplo, si tienes un entero podrías hacer algo así:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def highlight_col(column, bool_masks, color_list, default="white"):        
    cond_bg_style = [f'background-color: {color}' for color in color_list]
    default_bg_style = f'background-color:{default}'
    a =  np.select(bool_masks, cond_bg_style, default=default_bg_style)
    print(a)
    return a

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1254, 4554, 1485, 1, 26525, -14],
                   "B": [4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 2]}
                  )

masks = [np.abs(df.A) // 10 ** np.log10(np.abs(df.A)).astype(int) == 1]
colors = ["red"]

styled = df.style.apply(highlight_col, subset=["B"], bool_masks=masks, color_list=colors)
styled.to_excel("bar.xlsx", sheet_name='Hoja1')
```

Lo cual nos marca con  fondo rojo las celdas de la columna `B` si el entero de la celda de esa fila en la columna `A` tiene `1` como primer dígito (se ignora el signo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo
Este es mi aporte al foro: función sombrear con style.applymap
ver: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-conditional-formatting-in-pandas-8783035071ee

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris.sample(n=10, random_state=1)

def sombrear(val,ini,fin,colorFondo):
    condition = (val >= ini) & (val <= fin)
    color = 'red' if condition else 'black'
    background_color= colorFondo if condition else 'normal'
    font_size = '15px' if condition else '1em'
    font_family = 'cursive' if condition else 'serif'
    font_weight = 'bold' if condition else 'normal'
    return 'color: {}; background-color: {}; font-size: {}; font-family: {}; font-weight: {}'.format(color,background_color,font_size,font_family,font_weight)

df.style.applymap(sombrear,ini=1,fin=3,colorFondo='blue', subset=['sepal_length',   'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])\
.applymap(sombrear,ini=3.1,fin=5,colorFondo='yellow', subset=['sepal_length',   'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])\
.applymap(sombrear,ini=5.6,fin=8,colorFondo='green', subset=['sepal_length',    'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, es genial que quieras aportar, aunque seria mucho mejor si das una breve explicación de lo que hace tu código, considera que los usuarios nuevos con poca experiencia no entenderán tu respuesta, por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), si agregas enlaces no olvides citar las partes que veas mas importantes en tu respuesta, ya que el contenido del enlace en algún momento podría llegar a desaparecer. ;)