# Agregar color a una celda de un dataframe si cumplen varias condiciones

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, style

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Requiero agregar color a unas celdas especificas de los registros que cumplan varias condiciones. Tengo el siguiente **dataframe**

```
      Departamento      Municipio       Zona de dificil Acceso
   0            CAUCA    ARGELIA                     NO
   1  VALLE DEL CAUCA       CALI                     NO
   2            CAUCA    POPAYAN                     NO
   3            CAUCA     BALBOA                     NO
```

Encontré este ejemplo y con esto me estoy basando para resolver mi problema: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193521/agregar-background-a-una-celda-en-funci%c3%b3n-de-una-condici%c3%b3n[1]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193521/agregar-background-a-una-celda-en-funci%c3%b3n-de-una-condici%c3%b3n%5B1%5D)

En resumidas cuentas, el ejemplo me pide usar **pandas.style.apply** y crear una pequeña funcion que no me queda del todo clara pero ahí asigna el color:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
datos=[["CAUCA","ARGELIA","NO"],["VALLE DEL CAUCA","CALI","NO"],["CAUCA","POPAYAN","NO"], 
["CAUCA","BALBOA","NO"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=["Departamento","Municipio","Zona de dificil Acceso"])
listaMunicipios=["ARGELIA","PALOQUEMADO","PAMPLONA"]
color=["red"]
```

Arriba creo el **df** de prueba y creo la lista color. Luego copie y pegue la funcion que aparece en el ejemplo:

```
def funciomAgregarColores(column, bool_masks, color_list, default="white"):
 cond_bg_style = [f'background-color: {color}' for color in color_list]
 default_bg_style = f'background-color:{default}'
 a =  np.select(bool_masks, cond_bg_style, default=default_bg_style)
 print(a)
 return a
```

Aquí principalmente piden una mascara boolena que es **masks** y es aquí donde tengo el **problema** en cara a mi situación ¿Por qué? Bueno, para señalar con color algunas casillas estos registros deben cumplir con dos condiciones:
1.Sí los registros en la columna **Municipio** estan en la lista **listaMunicipios** Y además en la columna **Zona de dificil Acceso** Debe ser NO y el problema esta cuando hago la cimprobacion si el registro tiene municipios que estan en **listaMunicipios**

```
masks=[(df.iloc[x,2]=="NO") and (df.iloc[x,1] in listaMunicipios) for x in range(len(df))]
```

Tengo que usar un **for** para hacer la comprobación de que registros cumplen con estar en **listaMunicipios** y la otra condicion no me pone problema. Ya cuando ejecuto la linea me sale todo ok pero cuando ejecuto:

```
styled=df.style.apply(funciomAgregarColores,subset=["Zona de dificil Acceso"],bool_masks=masks,color_list=color)
```

Me sale este error cuando imprimo **styled**:

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:666, in select(condlist, choicelist, default)
664 # Check the size of condlist and choicelist are the same, or abort.
665 if len(condlist) != len(choicelist):
666     raise ValueError(
667         'list of cases must be same length as list of conditions')
669 # Now that the dtype is known, handle the deprecated select([], []) case
670 if len(condlist) == 0:

ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions
```

Si la mascara fuera más sencilla como

```
masks2=[df.Municipio=="ARGELIA"]
```

Me devuelve un objeto de tamaño 1 pero me dice que es una lista pero si con la mascara que utilice me dice que el tamaño es 4 pero es una lista

```
type(masks)
len(masks)
type(masks2)
len(masks2)
```

No se que hacer y no veo como cumplir mi tarea ¿Que me recomiendan leer o revisar? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, el problema es sencillo. Si te das cuenta, en la respuesta original `masks` es una lista de máscaras o filtros

```
masks = [data.A >= 0,
        (data.A >= -1) & (data.A < 0),
         data.A < -1
        ]
```

En este caso tenemos tres filtros o máscaras.

Lo que tu haces aquí:

```
masks=[(df.iloc[x,2]=="NO") and (df.iloc[x,1] in listaMunicipios) for x in range(len(df))]
```

Devuelve una sola lista, así:

```
[True, False, False, False]
```

Pero lo que necesitas en máscaras es una lista de listas (Filtros/Máscaras) por lo que necesitarías esto:

```
[[True, False, False, False]]
```

Si agregas los corchetes externos a tus máscaras de esta forma:

```
masks = [[(df.iloc[x,2]=="NO") and (df.iloc[x,1] in listaMunicipios) for x in range(len(df))]]
```

El código ya funciona.

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

En este caso tu comprensión de listas te devuelve la lista de booleanos que requiere la función pero hay una mejor forma de hacerlo ya que los ciclos van a consumir mucho tiempo si el `dataset` incrementa el tamaño

La forma óptima para obtener las máscaras sería así:

```
masks = [df['Municipio'].isin(listaMunicipios) & df['Zona de dificil Acceso'].eq('NO')]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datos=[["CAUCA","ARGELIA","NO"],["VALLE DEL CAUCA","CALI","NO"],["CAUCA","POPAYAN","NO"], 
["CAUCA","BALBOA","NO"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=["Departamento","Municipio","Zona de dificil Acceso"])

listaMunicipios=["ARGELIA","PALOQUEMADO","PAMPLONA"]
color=["red"]

def funciomAgregarColores(column, bool_masks, color_list, default="white"):
    cond_bg_style = [f'background-color: {color}' for color in color_list]
    default_bg_style = f'background-color:{default}'
    return np.select(bool_masks, cond_bg_style, default=default_bg_style)

masks = [df['Municipio'].isin(listaMunicipios) & df['Zona de dificil Acceso'].eq('NO')]
styled = df.style.apply(funciomAgregarColores,subset=["Zona de dificil Acceso"],bool_masks=masks,color_list=color)
```

Al imprimir `styled` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me tenía pensando y era algo sencillo. ¿Que me recomiendas leer sobre las listas booleanas?  parte de mi duda era que no entendía bien las listas booleanas  y de que tipo son, porque buscando no encontré mucho o no entendía lo que encontraba.

Comment: Otra cosa ¿Explique bien el problema? o Que me recomiendas para próximas publicaciones?

Comment: Si te refieres al uso de listas booleanas con los `dataframes` entonces únicamente son filtros, devuelven una lista con puros valores booleanos (`True`, `False`). Yo te recomendaría practicar seleccionar diferentes filas de tu `dataframe`.

Answer (score 1):

Cordial saludo
Tal vez una solución mas simple sea emplear style.highlight_between

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.highlight_between.html

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris.sample(n=10, random_state=1)

df.style.highlight_between(left=1, right = 3, inclusive ='both', color= 'blue',subset=['sepal_length',  'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])\
.highlight_between(left=3.1, right = 5, inclusive ='both', color= 'yellow',subset=['sepal_length',  'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])\
.highlight_between(left=5.6, right = 8, inclusive ='both', color= 'green',subset=['sepal_length',   'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])\
.highlight_between(left='versicolor',right = 'versicolor',  color= 'pink',subset=['species'])\
.highlight_between(left='setosa',right = 'setosa',  color= 'purple',subset=['species'])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo
Agrego aquí la función sombrear, con style.applymap que les podría servir
#ver
#https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-conditional-formatting-in-pandas-8783035071ee

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris.sample(n=10, random_state=1)

def sombrear(val,ini,fin,colorFondo):
    condition = (val >= ini) & (val <= fin)
    color = 'red' if condition else 'black'
    background_color= colorFondo if condition else 'normal'
    font_size = '15px' if condition else '1em'
    font_family = 'cursive' if condition else 'serif'
    font_weight = 'bold' if condition else 'normal'
    return 'color: {}; background-color: {}; font-size: {}; font-family: {}; font-weight: {}'.format(color,background_color,font_size,font_family,font_weight)

df.style.applymap(sombrear,ini=1,fin=3,colorFondo='blue', subset=['sepal_length',   'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])\
.applymap(sombrear,ini=3.1,fin=5,colorFondo='yellow', subset=['sepal_length',   'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])\
.applymap(sombrear,ini=5.6,fin=8,colorFondo='green', subset=['sepal_length',    'sepal_width',  'petal_length', 'petal_width'])
```

[image: Resultado ejecución Función Sombrear]

Comment: Saludos @CarlosArturoCastroCastro, cuando tengas la misma respuesta para dos preguntas diferentes siempre puedes [linkear](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/573998/146637) la misma en un **"comentario"**, de esa forma si a OP le sirvió tu respuesta también podrá puntuar la misma. ;)

Comment: También podría servirte lo siguiente: [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-sitio/3765#3765).

Comment: Cordial saludo @Israel-ICM
Entendido!